# Update Ember model attribute in component

Tags: ember.js

I have the following bit of code in an Ember component:

```
markResolved() {
  let reportingFailure = this.get('reportingFailure');
  reportingFailure.resolvedAt = '2017-01-01';
  reportingFailure.save();
}
```

The HTTP request is firing as expected but the `resolved_at` attribute is not getting set.

What do I have to do differently to get the attribute to set?

Answer (score 0):

How is `reportingFailure`defined? Due to the `save`method call, I assume it's an ember-data model.
Try to use .set() to change the resolvedAt attribute?:

```
markResolved() {
  let reportingFailure = this.get('reportingFailure');
  reportingFailure.set('resolvedAt', '2017-01-01');
  reportingFailure.save();
}
```